# How to get a list of tables for a specific database when connected using sysmaster user in Informix?

Tags: sql, database, informix

Is there a query to get the list of tables and their corresponding max size and size for a specific database when connected with sysmaster user in Informix?

I only can get the size of the given table when I am connected to its corresponding database, but that is not the case. I want to be able to get the table max size and size when I am only connected with sysmaster user. Is there another admin user/database which has such access to all tables information from all databases in Informix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the size of a informix table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54067366/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-informix-table)

Comment: No I don't think so. I want to connect to Informix only once with an Admin user and get databases, schemas and tables information. When I am connected to "sysmaster" database, I don't see the table which I have created within another database.

Comment: If you're connected to `sysmaster` as user `informix`, you can interrogate the information for other databases within the instance.  However, you can also find most of the information you need in the `sysmaster` database in the (pseudo-)table `systabnames` and the view `systabinfo` — join on `systabnames.partnum` and `systabinfo.ti_partnum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
   select tn.partnum, tn.dbsname, tn.owner, tn.tabname
         , pt.lockid, pt.flags, pt.flags2
         , pt.rowsize, pt.ncols, pt.pagesize
         , dbinfo('utc_to_datetime',pt.created) as created
         , pt.nrows, pt.nptotal, pt.npused, pt.npdata
         , pt.nrows * pt.rowsize as tamanho_bytes
         , (pt.nptotal * pt.pagesize) /1024 as total_kb
         , (pt.npused  * pt.pagesize) /1024 as used_kb
         , (pt.npdata  * pt.pagesize) /1024 as data_kb
         , ((pt.nptotal - pt.npused) * pt.pagesize) /1024 as free_kb
         , pt.nextns as extents
         , pt.ninserts
         , pt.nupdates
         , pt.ndeletes
         , coalesce(pt.serialv,pt.cur_serial8,pt.cur_bigserial)::bigint serial
         , pta_oldvers
         , pta_newvers
    from sysmaster:sysptnhdr pt
    left join sysmaster:systabnames tn on tn.partnum = pt.partnum
```

TBLspaces are listed too and fragmented tables are showed separated where you can group by lockid column (~partnum).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how I can also get the same thing for schemas? I mean schema size and its max size.

Comment: The informix doesn't work with schema, if you usually work with Oracle, it's a different way to think. Informix work with databases, like SqlServer, MySQL, etc. Anyway, if you want to get the size of the "schema" which means "user" just group by the `systabnames.owner` field , if you want sumarize for database, use the `dbsname` field.  Not sure what you think as schema size / max size , maybe you mean space used / space allocated ,if yes this SQL already return that.